# Using wildcards to get URLs from a string

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio C# and want to list wildcard instances in a string that are URls. I've used regex with Perl for years, but I just cannot figure it out in C#. For the string, there may not be any or there could be one or more urls.

str = "This has more than one URL http://findme.com/lost and another one named http://www.amidumb.net but then there is this one https://hello.ua/findme/ifyoucan/ at last."

I want to list iamlost.com, [www.amidumb.net](http://www.amidumb.net) and hello.ua

This is where I am:

```
string pattern = @"\/\/(.*)\/(.*)";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(newLineItem);
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
while(m.Success) {
  Console.WriteLine(m + "\n");
  m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

When I run the above, it prints the whole line after the first instance of ":" starting with the first occurance of "//".

It seems like I should be able to select the first (.*) after // and each one after that.

I'm gussing I somehow need to add each found instance to a list but I am totally lost. Am I even headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get what you are looking for I believe.

```
void Main()
{
    var rawString = "This has more than one URL http://findme.com/lost and another one named http://www.amidumb.net but then there is this one https://hello.ua/findme/ifyoucan/ at last.";
    var urlList = UrlMaker(rawString);
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public List<string> UrlMaker(string input)
{
    List<string> urls = new List<string>();
    var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var rawString = input;
    foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
    {
        if (m.Value.Contains("http"))
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(m.Value);
            urls.Add(url.Host);
        }
        else
        {

            urls.Add(m.Value);
        }
    }
    
    return urls;
}
```

this code outputs:

[image]

Comment: mathis1337, that is exactly what I needed. I ran it on a decent size list and it seems to have caught everything. I will spend a little time figuring out why it works and try adapting it to something else totally unrelated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mr.Coz feel free to make this as a correct answer then. If you need me to adapt it to your use case I should be able to also.